# Retrieve value of select query in a table column

Tags: sql-server

I need an alternative to cursor/while loop for below query:

We have a table as given in below screen shot containing the following columns: `ID`, `Module`, `Query`.  The table contains nearly 100,000 records.  Currently we are using cursor and a while loop to insert the output of the select query to a temporary table which we are joining with the actual table to update based on `ID`.

[image]

I need a help in writing a query that takes the `Query` column as input and gives the result as value like a function.

I tried creating a function which executes dynamic SQL but it failed because `EXEC` and `sp_executesql` aren't allowed within a function. Attempts to use a stored procedure also didn't work because we can pass only one query as a parameter from this table to get output as value.

Each query returns a single value (one column, one row). Different queries may return values with different datatypes; all should be converted to `nvarchar`.

Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: .NET application

Comment: Can you write an example query with a placeholder for the unknown part? How do you specify which queries need to be passed in? Can you also explain why you have this requirement?

Comment: assuming all the query values return the same output, can you just append "insert into [Result] ([Field1])" to the beginning and then use the stuff function to append some or all of your [Query] values with "union all" between them? -- then execute that as dynamic sql either all together or in batches (not sure if there is a limit on how many selects you can union together).

Comment: @theo all the query values return the same output: No it will be different.  

can you please provide a small example that i can use with union as you said.

Comment: Step 1: `INSERT INTO QueryList (Name, Query) VALUES ('BadBobbyTables', 'DROP TABLE QueryList;') ;` Step 2: Wait for query list to self-detonate.

Answer (score 6):

I've tested the following (in SQL Server 2014, but it should work at least as far back at 2008), and I believe it does what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE QueryList (Id int, Name nvarchar(128), Query nvarchar(4000));

INSERT INTO QueryList
VALUES (1, 'Date', 'SELECT GETDATE()')
      ,(2, 'String', 'SELECT ''What''''s this? Just a varchar string...'' as StrVal')
      ,(3, 'Server', 'SELECT @@SERVERNAME')
;

CREATE TABLE results (Id int, Name nvarchar(128), Result nvarchar(4000));

-----

DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(max);

SELECT @stmt = stuff( (SELECT N'UNION ALL SELECT TOP (1) ' + CAST(Id as nvarchar(10))
                             +N' as Id, ''' + Name + N''', CAST(qr.[Result] as nvarchar(4000)) as [Result] '
                             +N'FROM (' + Query + N') AS qr ([Result])
'
                         FROM QueryList
                          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
                     ,1,9,'INSERT INTO results') + ';'
;

SELECT @stmt; -- FOR TESTING - displays the resulting query

EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt;

SELECT * FROM results;
```

The central query takes all the records from `#QueryList`, and builds an `INSERT` statement to place the id, name, and the query result from each row into the `#results` temp table. Each row's values are in their own `SELECT` statement, and all the statements are combined into a single result set with `UNION ALL`. I have taken text files with thousands of rows, converted each one into a similar `SELECT ... UNION ALL`, and used that to successfully insert thousands of records into SQL Server tables; I don't expect the number of statements being unioned together to be an issue (but I can't guarantee there isn't a limit at some point).

If you haven't seen it before, this uses `FOR XML PATH` to concatenate the `UNION ALL SELECT ...` from each row's values into a single string, the `STUFF` replaces the first `UNION ALL` with the actual `INSERT INTO #results`. See [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/#Toc205129485) for more information on aggregating string data across multiple rows (or, move to SQL 2017 and use `STRING_AGG()`).

Something else that you may not have seen before is `FROM (<subquery>) AS qr ([Result])`. Just as the `AS qr` makes `qr` and alias for the subquery, `([Result])` provides a list of aliases for the columns (in our case, column) in the subquery.

Here's the query that's built from the above data:

```
INSERT INTO #results SELECT TOP (1) 1 as Id, 'Date', CAST(qr.[Result] as nvarchar(4000)) as [Result] FROM (SELECT GETDATE()) AS qr ([Result])
UNION ALL SELECT TOP (1) 2 as Id, 'String', CAST(qr.[Result] as nvarchar(4000)) as [Result] FROM (SELECT 'This is just a varchar string' as StrVal) AS qr ([Result])
UNION ALL SELECT TOP (1) 3 as Id, 'Server', CAST(qr.[Result] as nvarchar(4000)) as [Result] FROM (SELECT @@SERVERNAME) AS qr ([Result])
;
```

And, the contents of `#results` after the query is executed:

```
Id   Name     Result
---- -------- --------------------------------------
1    Date     Jul 14 2017 12:19PM
2    String   What's this? Just a varchar string...
3    Server   MYSERVERNAME\INSTANCE
```

Notes:

- If your query cannot trivially be used as a subquery (for instance, if you had a query in `#QueryList` that used a CTE), this will fail.
- If you included a closing `;` at the end of a query in #`QueryList`, it will fail (special case of not being trivially used as a subquery; I almost included this in my `#QueryList` queries, by force of habit).
- To be on the safe side, this allows for the possibility that some query may return multiple rows, and simply selects the first row as the "right" value, at random.
- If you do run into an issue with the number of statements being combined via `UNION ALL`, you can break this down into smaller chunks. Assuming that `Id` and `Name` taken together, are unique in #`QueryList`, then:

  ```
  SELECT @stmt = stuff( (SELECT TOP (10000) N'UNION ALL SELECT TOP (1) ' + CAST(ql.Id as nvarchar(10))
                                          +N' as Id, ''' +ql. Name + N''', CAST(qr.[Result] as nvarchar(4000)) as [Result] '
                                          +N'FROM (' + ql.Query + N') AS qr ([Result])
  '
                           FROM #QueryList ql
                                  LEFT  JOIN #results r ON (ql.Id = r.Id AND ql.Name = r.Name)
                          WHERE r.Id IS NULL
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
                       ,1,9,'INSERT INTO results') + ';'
  ;
  ```

  would let you grab 1000 `#QueryList` rows at a time, and only grab ones where the `Id` and `Name` don't already exist in `#results`. You'd have to put this in a loop, and keep going until there were no more rows left in `#QueryList`. `@stmt` is `NULL` if there are no more rows to process, so you could use that to break out of the loop.

  Again, I *don't* expect this to be an issue. And, even if it is, while it takes you back to a `WHILE` loop, you're dealing with 10,000 (or more) rows at a time, not one. It should be faster than your current cursor implementation.

  And - if you find that there are some queries that cause problems, this could be useful for testing; go through subsets of data until you find a set that doesn't work, then check those queries to see if there's an issue with one.

Comment: I would really appreciate and very thankful for giving me solution with an example , i made it to work, but i am using a loop to finish in batches of the queries, because as i already said i have 53000 records like this if i build dynamically i am able to get 220 records single time to get inserted into #result table,  and one more problem i am not able to handle is, As we are using nvarchar(4000) for @stmt so it can build it can upto allowed characters,  at end of built query half finished or half broken i can say ex: **select TOP(1) 221 as Id, 'ABCD', CAST(qr.[Resu **

Comment: The example I provided uses `nvarchar(max)`. Is there a reason you can't use that? If you must use `nvarchar(4000)`, all I can recommend is that you check the maximum length of a query, and keep the number of rows you process at a time small enough that you won't go over 4000 characters total, using the `TOP (X)` version of the query.